# Android - get photos from database with AsyncTask - doInBackGround not starting

Tags: android

I'm having a problem with my program. I'm calling my `getImages()` function in `onCreate()` but when I tried debugging it, I discovered that `doInBackground()` function doesn't actually start. I've seen many people had the same problem but none of the solutions provided were of any help.
Here is how my main activity looks like:

```
public class poi_photos extends ActionBarActivity {


    public static ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<>();
    public static  GridView gridView;

    // Retrieve PHOTOS from database
    String myJSON;

    private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL_USER = "email_user";
    private static final String TAG_POI_NAME = "poi_name";
    private static final String TAG_PHOTO_URL = "photo_url";

    JSONArray photos = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> photoList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> numsList;

    // GALLERY
    private FeatureCoverFlow mCoverFlow;
    private CoverFlowAdapter Adapter;
    private ArrayList<GameEntity> mData = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private TextSwitcher mTitle;


    String photo_url2;

    // Camera Activity
    Button btpic, btnup;
    private Uri fileUri;
    String picturePath;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Bitmap photo;
    String ba1;
    static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    //  MENU
    String TITLES[] = {"Home", "Profile", "Travel", "POIs Map", "Find your friends!", "Take Picture"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.ic_prof, R.drawable.ic_travel, R.drawable.ic_poi, R.drawable.ic_friends_map, R.drawable.ic_photo};
    String NAME = MainActivity.username;
    String EMAIL = MainActivity.user_email;

    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_photos);




        FloatingActionButton add_comment = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_poi_comments);
        add_comment.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.Blonde));
        add_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(poi_photos.this, MarkerActivity.class));
            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton see_photos = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_add_photo);
        see_photos.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.Blonde));
        see_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takepic();
            }
        });

        image_urls.clear();

        if (image_urls.isEmpty())
        {
            getImages();
        }

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(poi_photos.this, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", adapter.imageUrls.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        // MENU
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, this);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager

        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(poi_photos.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


                if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    Drawer.closeDrawers();
                    //   Toast.makeText(map.this,"The Item Clicked is: "+recyclerView.getChildPosition(child),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    switch (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)) {
                        case 1:
                            Intent a = new Intent(poi_photos.this, myprofile.class);
                            startActivity(a);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Intent b = new Intent(poi_photos.this, profile.class);
                            startActivity(b);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Intent c = new Intent(poi_photos.this, ShortPath.class);
                            startActivity(c);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Intent e = new Intent(poi_photos.this, FriendsMap.class);
                            startActivity(e);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            //Camera Activity
                            if (hasCamera()) {
                                // create intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                                // start camera activity
                                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }


        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_poi_photos, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // method to check if you have a Camera
    private boolean hasCamera() {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }


    // CAMERA ACTIVITY

    private void takepic() {
        // Check Camera
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // Open default camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // Cursor to get image uri to display

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


            // Show pop up window
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(poi_photos.this);
            View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_photo, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(poi_photos.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_photo);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Keep the photo!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            upload(); // upload photo to folder
                            upload2(); // upload photo to database
                        }
                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // create an alert dialog
            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    // upload photo to database
    private void upload() {
        // Image location URL
        Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);

        // Image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

        // Upload image to server
        new uploadToServer().execute();
    }


    public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(poi_photos.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("Wait uploading image!");
            pd.show();
        }


        // insert photo
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            photo_url2 = map.markername + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", photo_url2));
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxx/photo.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop " + st);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.hide();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // insert photo
    private void upload2() {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        InputStream is = null;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_user", MainActivity.user_email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("poi_name", map.markername));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo_url", photo_url2));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http:xxxxx/photo_out.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            String msg = "Data has been sent successfully";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_Tag");
            e.printStackTrace();
            String msg2 = "Log_Tag";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Log_Tag", "IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            String msg3 = "IOException";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    // GETTING PHOTOS FROM DATABASE
    protected void showList() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            photos = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = photos.getJSONObject(i);
                String email_user = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL_USER);
                String poi_name = c.getString(TAG_POI_NAME);
                String photo_url = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO_URL);

                if ((poi_name.substring(0, 4)).equals(map.markername) && photo_url!=null) {
                   // add to the picasso gallery
                    photo_url="http://romcad.ro/poi/photos/"+photo_url;
                   image_urls.add(photo_url);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void getImages() {
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxx/table_photo_out.php");

                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception squish) {
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                myJSON = result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

}
```

Any idea/ tip what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write the class GetDataJSON into the method getImages()?

Try to delete the method around your class and instead of calling getImages() call

new getDataJSON().execute(yourString);